# auth.logout is not working in my app using firebase facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, firebase

I have tried basic steps of Firebase Facebook authentication. So in my app the user can successfully log in using Firebase Facebook authentication. But I have a problem in logout.

I used logout button and bind click event on that, as shown below:

```
$(function(){
    $('#lgout').click(function(){   
       auth.logout();
    });
});
```

For login I use this code:

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://my-firebase-url');
    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
          if (error) {
            // an error occurred while attempting login
            alert("please login first");
          } else if (user) {
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            //alert('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                $('#user').text("Welcome  "+data.name);
                }
            });
          } else {
            // user is logged out
            //auth.login('facebook');
          }
        });
        auth.login('facebook');
```

In login also, I got one problem as you can see in `else` part I used `auth.login('facebook');` that is not working showing error 
`auth is not defined`. But if I used outside of `else` then it working fine.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you're seeing with logout()? It was unclear from your question. What is behaving differently than you expected? Are you seeing errors in the console?

Comment: no, it didn't give any error at console. my problem is when i click on logout button,my fb session should expire right? so that's not happening here

Comment: When you call `logout()`, your Firebase Simple Login session is expired, but you are still logged into Facebook, and that application is still authenticated in your Facebook account. Calling `login()` again may appear instantaneous, and not ask the user to approve the application again, which is expected behavior from Facebook Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate from the issue regarding `auth.logout()`, you should never call `auth.login('facebook');` from within this callback. Rather, it should be called after a user click event, as your browser will prevent the Facebook pop-up from launching.

From https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html:

> Third-party authentication methods use a browser pop-up window to
>   prompt the user to sign-in, approve the application, and return the
>   user's data to the requesting application. Most modern browsers will
>   block the opening of this pop-up window unless it was invoked by
>   direct user action.
>
> For that reason, we recommend that you only invoke the "login()"
>   method for third-party authentication methods upon user click.

Comment: oky thanks, got it. but what about auth.logout() ? why its not working in my case ? any idea